# Some kind of PHP shortcodes

Tags: php

I saw this used by some PHP frameworks.. but I have no idea how can it be done.. or how to make it.

Basicly it's a function ( i think ) that get's called. This is how it looks

```
{name} or {{name}}
```

How is it possible to make something like this in PHP?

Comment: Look at the source for the frameworks that you saw it in. As Quentin said, it may be Mustache. However, it could be one of many templating languages (Smarty and Twig also come to mind). Simple variable replacement can be handled by `str_replace`, but I think what you're getting at is a _much_ larger question than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) template syntax, the [source code](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) of a PHP implementation is available.